# Allowing python mac app to run sudo script

Tags: python, macos, shell, applescript, py2app

I'm making a small app that allows me through a status bar toggle to connect to a vpn and to run a small routing shell script. To build this app I used a library called rumps and py2app to generate the mac app.

I made the following python script that handles the launch of the vpn + the shell script :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import rumps
from subprocess import call

class MyVPNStatusBarApp(rumps.App):

    @rumps.clicked("MyVPN ON")
    def vpn_on(self, _):
        script_on = False
        try_number = 0
        call("scutil --nc start \"MyVPN\"", shell=True)
        while script_on == False:
            if call("scutil --nc show \"MyVPN\" | grep  -q \"Connected\"", shell=True) == 0:
                call("/usr/bin/osascript -e \'do shell script \"./web_routes.sh args 2>&1 etc\" with administrator privileges\'", shell=True)
                rumps.notification(
                    "VPN Status", "VPN + Internet Access", 'Granted')
                script_on = True
            elif try_number == 20:
                print 'TIME OUT'
                return     
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                try_number += 1 

    @rumps.clicked("MyVPN OFF")
    def vpn_off(self, _):
        call("scutil --nc stop \"MyVPN\"", shell=True)
        rumps.notification(
            "VPN Status", "VPN OFF", 'Internet should work')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyVPNStatusBarApp("VPN").run()
```

My py2app setup file is as follow :

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'plist': {
        'LSUIElement': True,
    },
    'packages': ['rumps'],
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    name='MyVPN',
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

The problem is that when I run my main.py in the shell, the app is able to run the shell script. But when I make the bundled app, the app seems not able to run the shell script even after asking me for the admin password.

Do somebody know what might be the issue ?

Comment: Did you try adding `sudo` to the commands called from your script? Also try running the bundled app as root user. `sudo open -a <app name>`

Answer (score 2):

So the issue was that the shell script wasn't bundled with the generated app. I figured out this by putting just after the imports:

```
rumps.debug_mode(True)
```

and running the generated app in the shell like this:

```
./dist/MyVPN.app/Contents/MacOS/MyVPN
```

The solution was to generate the app with this command:

```
> sudo python setup.py py2app --resources web_routes.sh
```

This way allows the shell script to be bundled with the app.